# create a bibtex archive with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, bibtex

I'm trying to create a code that, based on informations from BD, creates a bibtex archive. That's what I got:

```
<?php
include("classe/conexao.php");

session_start();
$_SESSION[id_tese_especifica] = $_GET['id'];

$result = pg_query("SELECT titulo, id, data, autor_nome FROM teses ORDER BY data DESC");
$arr = pg_fetch_array($result);

echo "@phdthesis{phpthesis,
  author={" . $arr[0] . "},
  title={" . $arr[6] . " " . $arr[3] . "},
  month={" . $arr[2] . "}";

$name = $_GET['id'] . ".bib";
$file = fopen($name, 'a');
$text = "test (it doesn't appears on archive and I don't know why, so I used the echo above and worked, but this is what should be on archive, or isn't?)";
fwrite($file, $text);

readfile($file);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Expires: 0');

?>
```

After that, it downloads an archive named 'Resource id #6', why? The name should be based on this: `$name = $_GET['id'] . ".bib"`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because filename is stored in a `$name` variable in your code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
```

And `$file` variable is a resource, connected with open file.

And by the way - you don't close the file properly.

```
fclose($fp); // $fp is NOT defined, your pointer is in $file variable
```

Proper code for closing is:

```
fclose($file);
```

**Next**, rearrange your code. 
First of all - headers should be sent **BEFORE** any output.
What you currently have is some mix of errors, which accidentally show you something that you want.

Proper code should be:

```
$name = $_GET['id'] . ".bib"; 
// first of all - set proper headers:
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Expires: 0');

// next - do a query
$result = pg_query("SELECT titulo, id, data, autor_nome FROM teses ORDER BY data DESC");
$arr = pg_fetch_array($result);

// use echo for testing purposes only
// cause echo considered as a content of your file
echo "@phdthesis{phpthesis,
    author={" . $arr[0] . "},
    title={" . $arr[6] . " " . $arr[3] . "},
    month={" . $arr[2] . "}";

$fp = fopen($name, 'a');
$text = "test (it doesn't appears on archive and I don't know why, so I used the echo above and worked, but this is what should be on archive, or isn't?)";
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);   // don't forget to close file for saving newly added data

readfile($name);   // readfile takes a filename, not a handler.
die();    // end your script cause in other case all other data will be outputted too
```

Comment: Got it! Worked like a charm! And about the $text variable? Why it has no result in the archive and the 'echo "@phdthesis{php.......' does?

Comment: You just saved me. Thank you a lot. It is good to know what you explained. Thank you, man :)